# Why won't my unordered list centre properly?

Tags: html, css

It seemingly attempts to centre, but in actuality is a few pixels off. It's really annoying.

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiXf8.png

My code:

HTML:

```
<body>
        <div class="menu-bar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>

        <div class="greeting"></div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-bar {
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande';
}

.menu-bar ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-bar li {
    display: inline;
}

.greeting {
    background: url('../media/pic.jpg');
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
}
```

Very frustrating. >_<

Comment: Are you including a standard reset.css file in your code anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Margin` and `Padding` both needs to be set to `0` unless you are using a [css reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) to avoid browser inconsistencies.

```
.menu-bar ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/93Vyw/1/).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Time to look into CSS resets as well. Thanks. :)

Comment: Never seen a Sheikh and a Heera thrown in together. +1 for the name.

Comment: @Jawad, lol... Thanks but My name is `Sheikh Muhammad Ansar Uddin Heera` and `Heera` is my nick name given by my father. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

UL has a default left margin which you haven't dealt with. Just add margin: 0;